# High FPS but frame drop/stutter

Tags: windows-8.1, gaming

First post here, highly respect this community so was my first port of call to ask. Tell me if it's the appropriate place to ask too :)

I've been working on this for hours yesterday and today, and would like ideas/input to help solve the problem.

Machine: Dell XPS 9530. i7 4712 HQ, NVIDIA GT 750 M, 16GB RAM, Windows 8.1

Problem: When playing games (specifically I've been trying TF2 and Besiege for the last two days) I get frame drop/stutter roughly every 2 seconds (In TF2, it stops producing frames for about 0.2-0.5 secs, in Besiege it actually skips back a few frames!!), despite having lowered the settings so that I can achieve roughly 240 fps.

It happens with both the NVIDIA card and the onboard Intel Graphics.

It happens whether VSync is enabled or not.

It can be a bit worse when lots is going on in game (explosions etc).

This did not use to be a problem, it's happened recently. It's quite bad and makes games unplayable.

My analysis: I know the computer is sufficiently powerful to play these games. I've played them on higher settings on universally lower spec/older machines. I've checked that CPU, RAM etc are not fully loaded. Also not an overheating issue.

Seems unlikely to be a driver issue as it happens with both the card and the onboard gfx.

??

What I've tried: I did a clean install of the latest NVIDIA driver.
I downgraded my BIOS after a recent upgrade.

Something that I don't know if might be relevant, I tried disabling VSync in game and enabling it along with triple buffering from the NVIDIA control panel. It saves the settings but does not apply, with fps way above 60 in game. (Enabling VSync makes things slightly better in game)

If we can't figure this out, I think I will resort to a format/clean install of Windows 10, but I'd really like to avoid that. Any help means huge amounts to me :)

EDIT: If you deem it helpful I can upload a short unlisted video on youtube to demonstrate.

Comment: Turns out I don't notice it in some other games...

Comment: If you are playing games on battery power then the stuttering which you describe is to be expected. Make sure you are always plugged in when playing games.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for the input. I've just fixed it (I was plugged in), the solution is pretty incredible, will post it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'VE FIXED IT!

The solution is the most incredible thing you will ever read.

I had subscribed to download some items from the steam workshop. I had noticed it was a bit buggy with the downloads stopping/starting and generally not working properly. Unsubscribed and voila problem solved. I guess it must have been momentarily chewing something up.